# CPU temperature reaches 90 degrees C

Tags: cpu, overheating

My laptop is Lenovo IdeaPad 110-15ACL with AMD E1-7010.

The CPU temperature reaches 90C and I can't even touch the laptop. Can this cause any harm to the laptop? what should I do?

Comment: Ensure that `thermald` (`apt list thermald`) is installed and operating.  Install tlp to assist with power management.  `sudo apt install tlp` followed by `sudo  tlp start`  .  Check that your laptop fan is operational.

Comment: And yes, excessive temperature can cause component failure, or fire.

Answer (score 2):

Try to check if fans are working correctly!

If fans are working correctly then open **system monitor application** from the start menu and check that how much percentage resources are being used by the Operating System.